# Genymotion devices are not visible after changing adb sdk path

Tags: android, adb, genymotion

I wanted to use react-native and install in genymotion device.
But for that I had to change the sdk path in Genymotion.
After changing the sdk path the genymotion devices are not visible in adb.
Let me know how to proceed with this

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path of SDK in Genymotion as & when it is required by doing the followings :

1. Open GenyMotion
2. Go to Settings -> ADB
3. check radio button for Use Custom Android Tools & Enter the location of your SDK.

Above stuff will not affect the devices that you had added to Genymotion previously. However, If your are unable to see you previously added devices do the following exercise :

1. Open GenyMotion
2. Go To Settings -> Virtual Box
3. Check the path given for virtual devices there
4. It looks something like this C:/Users/Your_PC_Name/AppData/Local/Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/ 
   (in windows OS)
   or it may be any other location.
5. Now, make sure all your devices are here. if they are not being listed you need to do a FRESH START by adding new devices.
6. ELSE IF you can see all the folders of your previously added devices.

Probably it is different location that GenyMotion searchs for the devices, So, Now you need to update the path for devices by performing the following steps :

1. Find the .virtualBox folder in your system, generally it is found at 
   C:\Users\Your_PC_Name.VirtualBox- (in windows OS)
2. Find file "VirtualBox.xml" 
   if you find  "VirtualBox.xml-prev" or  "VirtualBox.xml-tmp" instead of
   VirtualBox.xml
   2.1  make a copy of the "VirtualBox.xml-prev" file and renamed the copy to 
    "VirtualBox.xml"
3. Go to MachineRegistry TAG  & update src value for each MachineEntry i.e. your Genymotion Virtual Device.

Now, Restart GenyMotion. It should work.